# jQuery UI Droppable: how to drop the element where the mouse is released

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am using the Droppable method to make a container receive div elements.

This container is also sortable.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r5vrrcxv/2/

```
jQuery('#source').sortable();

jQuery('#receiver').sortable().droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "<div></div>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
    }
});
```

My problem: when I drag and drop elements into the receiver, the elements are always dropped at the bottom of the receiver.

What I am looking for: instead, as the elements in the receiver are sortable, I would like the elements dropped in the receiver to be positioned above or below the element where they are dropped nearby.

Is there a built-in event or method in Droppable or Sortable that would allow to do that?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you really need Droppable here.  Check out the "connect-lists" [demo](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) on jQueryUI.

This allows you to drag sortable elements from one list to another, in order. You connect the lists using the [connectWith](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-connectWith) option in the sortable object:

#### HTML:

```
<div id="source" class="connectedSortable">
    <div>aaaaaaa</div>
    <div>bbbbbbb</div>
    <div>ccccccc</div>
</div>


<div id="receiver" class="connectedSortable">
    <div>gggggggg</div>
    <div>hhhhhhhh</div>
    <div>iiiiiiii</div>
</div>
```

#### jQuery:

```
$( "#source, #receiver" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
}).disableSelection();
```

If you want the relationship to be one-way (ie. you can't drag the elements back to the source after dropping them in the receiver), you just declare the sortables separately:

```
$( "#source" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
}).disableSelection();

$( "#receiver" ).sortable().disableSelection();
```

Here's your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r5vrrcxv/3/